# How do I use an array instead of the variables in this repetitive function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

So, I have this little code in my js file:

```
window.onload = function Equal() {
  var a = 'b1'
  var b = 'box1'
  var bookstorname = localStorage.getItem(a)
  if (bookstorname == 1) {
    document.getElementById(b).setAttribute('checked','checked');
  }
  if (bookstorname == 0) {
    document.getElementById(b).removeAttribute('checked','checked');
  }
  var a = 'b2'
  var b = 'box2'
  var bookstorname = localStorage.getItem(a)
  if (bookstorname == 1) {
    document.getElementById(b).setAttribute('checked','checked');
  }
  if (bookstorname == 0) {
    document.getElementById(b).removeAttribute('checked','checked');
  }
}
```

The function *itself* is not important (it equals checkboxvalues set in the localstorage), but I execute it 2 times. First time with `var` `a` & `b` set to `'b1'` & `'box1'`. Then I run the script again (same script), but with `var` `a` & `b` set to `'b2'` & `'box2'`. Now, this code works, but my question is if there is a shorter way to write this? I can imagine some sort of array with a loop, but I could not get it to work for some reason. The 2 variables are pairs, and I know this might be a dumb question, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might separate common logic into another function

```js
window.onload = function Equal() {
  
  function extractFromStorage(a, b) {
    var bookstorname = localStorage.getItem(a)
    if (bookstorname == 1) {
      document.getElementById(b).setAttribute('checked','checked');
    }
    if (bookstorname == 0) {
      document.getElementById(b).removeAttribute('checked','checked');
    }
  }
  
  extractFromStorage('b1', 'box1');
  extractFromStorage('b2', 'box2');
}
```

Comment: Add a `else` statement rather than a second compare. That will cover the case of local storage being undefined. `} if (bookstorname == 0) {` becomes `} else {` and stop the need for running unnecessary code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a second function which will accept the local storage key and the checkbox id like

```
window.onload = function Equal() {
    setCheckboxState('box1', 'b1');
    setCheckboxState('box2', 'b2');
}

function setCheckboxState(id, key) {
    document.getElementById(id).checked = 1 == localStorage.getItem(key);
}
```

Comment: +1 for using the `.checked` property instead of adding and removing the `checked` attribute (which means `.defaultChecked`)

Comment: Just pointing out that that code if `'use strict'` is added will throw an error because `bookstorname` is undefined. If not using `"use strict"` it will incorrectly check the check box because `bookstorname` is `undefined` and if local storage is not found that will equal `undefined` as well resulting in `true`.

Comment: @Blindman67 sorry... it was suppose to be `1 == localStorage.getItem(key)`

Comment: Local storage returns strings so would be best practice to use `"1" === localStorage[key];` and using bracket notation rather than the function `getItem` is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
function doTheStuff(a, b) {

  var bookstorname = localStorage.getItem(a)

  if (bookstorname == 1) {

    document.getElementById(b).setAttribute('checked','checked');

  }

  if (bookstorname == 0) {

    document.getElementById(b).removeAttribute('checked','checked');

  }  

}



window.onload = function Equal() {

  doTheStuff('b1', 'box1');

  doTheStuff('b2', 'box2');

}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

There are several problems with your code.

- You do not check that the element you are stetting an attribute to
  exists.   You do not check if the `localStorage` item you get is
  defined.
- You pollute the global name space with the function name Equal.
- That function should not be named with a capital as it is not a Object generator.
- There is no need to use `setAttribute` and `removeAttribute`, in
  fact `removeAttribute` makes no sense in this case as you can not
  remove the checked attribute from the element. BTW why use `setAttribute` here and not for `window.onload`?
- The `checked` attribute is either true or false, it does not use the 
  string "checked"
- Binding the load event via the onload attribute is not safe as you may
  block 3rd party code, or worse 3rd party code may block you.
- There is no error checking. DOM pages are dynamic environments, pages
  have adverts and content from many places that can interfer with your
  code. Always code with this in mind. Check for possible errors and deal with them in a friendly way for the end user. In this case I used an alert, not friendly for a normal user but for you the coder.

My solution.

```
// add an event listener rather than replace the event listener
window.addEventListener(
    "load",  // for the load event
    function(){

        // the update function that is called for each item;
        var update = function(item){
            // the right hand side equates to true if the localstorage
            // is equal to "1". LocalStorage allways returns a string or
            // undefined if the key is not defined.
            item.element.checked = localStorage[item.storageName] === "1";
        }   

        // safe element getter     
        var getElement = function(eId){
            var e = document.getElementById(eId); // try and get the element
            if(e === null){  // does it exist?
                throw "Missing element:"+eId;  // no then we can not continue
                                               // the program stops here unless
                                               // you catch the error and deal with 
                                               // it gracefully.
            }
            return e; //ok return the element.
        }

        // Item creator. This creates a new item.
        // sName is the local storage name
        // eId id the element ID
        var item = function(sName, eId){
            return {
                storageName: sName,  // set the loaclStorage name
                element:getElement(eId); // get the element and check its safe
            };
        }

        // make it all safe
        try{
            // create an array of items.
            var items = [
                item("b1","box1"),
                item("b2","box2")
            ];
            // for each item update the element status
            items.forEach(update);
        }catch(e){
            alert("Could not update page?");
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistakes, I only began learning JavaScript some days ago, so I appreciate it. But not to worry, it's all for an offline document. By the time I put it online (if ever), I will have learned how to properly syntax and use JavaScript. Of course I ran the short course from w3schools, and some vids, but other than that, what is the best way to learn js?